# Rename all databases when doing a mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore, mongodb-4.2

I have a datadump but I need to change the name of every database while restoring them,
if a database is named "customers" it needs to be "customer2", "products" to "products2"

I can rename an individual database but that will take a lot of time to rename each database separately

`mongorestore --nsFrom='PetHotel.pets' --nsTo='PetHouse.pets' --nsInclude="PetHouse.*" dump/`

how to I rename all database in a dump?

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? Don't know much about MongoDB but if you have a text dump, a bit of sed (and maybe awk) can go a long way (in Linux)!

Comment: @Vérace, mongodumps are binary format, so could be difficult.

Comment: @Vérace I am using WSL2  but I don't think i can use sed or awk to rename them, doesn't seem like a viable option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be this one:

```
mongorestore --nsInclude="PetHotel.*" --nsFrom='PetHotel.*' --nsTo='PetHouse.*' dump/

mongorestore --nsInclude='*.*' --nsFrom='$database$.*' --nsTo='$database$2.*' dump/
```

First test it with option `--dryRun`

See [Change Collections' Namespaces during Restore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#change-collections--namespaces-during-restore)